# Why are there so many aliens?

Tags: dc, aliens, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In season 1 of *Supergirl* all the aliens were criminals from Fort Rozz but now, in season 2, there are loads of civilian aliens in the world just living amongst the humans in peace (mostly). So I guess I missed something but where did all the non-Fort Rozz aliens come from?

Comment: Most likely from space, since they are, you know, aliens :P     Some at least, like Lyra Strayd (Winn's girlfriend) and her brother Bastian are refugees using the (relatively) primitive Earth as a safe haven - very Men-in-Black-ish.

Answer (score 3):

They were previously in hiding. At the start of Season 2 the President signed the "Alien Amnesty Act", allowing those aliens that were hiding on Earth to come out of the shadows and live ordinary, peaceful lives.

> **Supergirl:** *Wait, the President is coming here?*
>
> **Alex:** *Yeah, she wants to tour the DEO while she's in National City to sign the Alien Amnesty Act.*
>
> **Supergirl:** *It's amazing, **an executive order allowing aliens on Earth to come out of the shadows and live as full citizens.***

As to *how* they got there, the short answer is that faster-than-light travel is readily available in the Superman universe. The mere existence of the DEO prior to Fort Rozz crashing shows that alien arrivals have been happening for decades before the start of the show.

Comment: It's amazing, the most unobscured exposition dialogue ever.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - It's a show for children. Don't expect Shakespeare

Comment: @Valorum - Where'd you get that idea? It's a show for the 18-40 viewing bloc, like almost all the other ones.

Comment: @Adamant - In that case it's unforgivably badly written